# query result coming same with or without where condition

Tags: sql

I am writing sql query for this **List all the names of all criminals who have had any of the crime code charges involved in crime ID 10089** problem statement but my result comes to be the same with or without where condition

```
select * 
from criminals c 
join crimes cms
on c.criminal_id = cms.criminal_id
join crime_charges cc on cc.crime_id=cms.crime_id
order by c.first, c.last;
where (cc.fine_amount is not null) and (cc.crime_id==10089);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.  What is a "crime code charge"?

Answer (score 1):

Use where condition before order by and remove the semicolon as it indicates the end of query ,so where condition is treated as a seperate query.

```
select * 
from criminals c 
join crimes cms
on c.criminal_id = cms.criminal_id
join crime_charges cc on cc.crime_id=cms.crime_id
where (cc.fine_amount is not null) and (cc.crime_id=10089)
order by c.first, c.last;
```

Comment: This query gives ORA-00936: missing expression this error

Answer (score 0):

This suggests `exists`.  However, I think a key component is determining whether a give charge is also a charge for 10089.  Window functions are a convenient way to handle that:

```
select c.* 
from criminals c 
where exists (select 1
              from crimes cr join
                   (select cc.*,
                           sum(case when cc.crime_id = 10089 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cc.crime_charge) as num_10089
                    from crime_charges cc
                   ) cc
                   on cr.crime_id = cc.crime_id
              where c.criminal_id = cr.criminal_id 
             )
order by c.first, c.last;
```

Note:  The problem statement says nothing about fines so I removed that logic.